# How to translate to antlr4 grammar ObjectLiteral[Yield]?

Tags: ecmascript-6, antlr4, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to translate the es6 grammar comming from:

- https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-lexical-grammar
- and https://gist.github.com/rbuckton/0d8c1f1c607f52f5ae37

My problem is that a lot of declarations contains something like this:

```
ObjectLiteral[Yield] :
 { }
 { PropertyDefinitionList[?Yield] }
 { PropertyDefinitionList[?Yield] , }
```

I would like to know if there is any translation to antlr4  for the previous lines.

Comment: Have you looked at existing grammars how they do that? E.g. look here: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/ecmascript

Comment: Yes, I already looked at that one first. However, that grammar is for ES5 or ES4, not sure. It doesn't have any Lexeme using `Yield`. Only the declaration for future reserved words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to follow the definitions in the [Grammar Notation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-grammar-notation) section of the spec. That is, a production with one parameter on the left-hand-side is an abbreviation for two parameter-less productions, one for each possible 'setting' of the parameter.

For example,

```
ObjectLiteral[Yield] :
  { }
  { PropertyDefinitionList[?Yield] }
  { PropertyDefinitionList[?Yield] , }
```

is an abbreviation for the two productions:

```
ObjectLiteral :
  { }
  { PropertyDefinitionList }
  { PropertyDefinitionList , }
```

and

```
ObjectLiteral_Yield :
  { }
  { PropertyDefinitionList_Yield }
  { PropertyDefinitionList_Yield , }
```